# Configuring Python Application based upon git branch

Tags: python, git, configuration

I've been thinking about ways to automatically setup configuration in my Python applications.

I usually use the following type of approach:

```
'''config.py'''
class Config(object):
    MAGIC_NUMBER = 44
    DEBUG = True

class Development(Config):
    LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'

class Production(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    REPORT_EMAIL_TO = ["ceo@example.com", "chief_ass_kicker@example.com"]
```

Typically, when I'm running the app in different ways I could do something like:

```
from config import Development, Production

do_something():
    if self.conf.DEBUG:
       pass

def __init__(self, config='Development'):
    if config == "production":
        self.conf = Production
    else:
        self.conf = Development
```

I like working like this because it makes sense, however I'm wondering if I can somehow integrate this into my git workflow too.

A lot of my applications have separate scripts, or modules that can be run alone, thus there isn't always a monolithic application to inherit configurations from some root location.

It would be cool if a lot of these scripts and seperate modules could check what branch is currently checked out and make their *default* configuration decisions based upon that, e.g., by looking for a class in `config.py` that shares the same name as the name of the currently checked out branch.

Is that possible, and what's the cleanest way to achieve it?

Is it a good/bad idea?

Comment: Why not have a different config.py in every branch? That way you simply import the config in your code and let the VCS (git in this case) take care of any divergence in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer [spinlok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401293/configuring-python-application-based-upon-git-branch#comment13417689_10401293)'s method, but yes, you can do pretty much anything you want in your `__init__`, e.g.:

```
import inspect, subprocess, sys

def __init__(self, config='via_git'):
    if config == 'via_git':
        gitsays = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'symbolic-ref', 'HEAD'])
        cbranch = gitsays.rstrip('\n').replace('refs/heads/', '', 1)
        # now you know which branch you're on...
        tbranch = cbranch.title() # foo -> Foo, for class name conventions
        classes = dict(inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
        if tbranch in classes:
            print 'automatically using', tbranch
            self.conf = classes[tbranch]
        else:
            print 'on branch', cbranch, 'so falling back to Production'
            self.conf = Production
    elif config == 'production':
        self.conf = Production
    else:
        self.conf = Development
```

This is, um, "slightly tested" (python 2.7).  Note that `check_output` will raise an exception if git can't get a symbolic ref, and this also depends on your working directory.  You can of course use other `subprocess` functions (to provide a different `cwd` for instance).